# firebase notification message is not closing before navigating to page?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications. when the app is in the foreground, I'm calling local notifications to display with `bigpicturestyle` mode.

But when app is in background how can I get notifications?

I have tried calling `onmessage` launch but the problem is when I wanted to navigate it to another actvity, it is coming like stack i.e page above page. I want to close notifcation manually before navigating

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print("onMessage: $message");
                  },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
          if(message['notificationType']=="tips"){
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Tipspage");
         },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print("onResume: $message");
        if(message['notificationType']=="tips"){
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Tipspage");
             },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic("all");

    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
```

Comment: Please make sure to add in all the relevant code so we can replicate the issue, as well as communicate a way to fix it.

Comment: @Derek  i have included sample code, for me navigation is working when app is closed but it is coming like page above page